# Collective term for acid/base; hydronium/hydroxide

Tags: acid-base, terminology

When writing about acids and bases it would seem very natural for me to abstract the set of both acids and bases and have a single noun for them, instead of cumbersomly listing them both each time. Compare anions and cations, where one can simply say 'ions' if one means both kinds.

Is there a established collective term? If not, what is the elegant way to speak about them?

About the same thing applies to hydronium/hydroxide. Is there a collective term? What about 'water ions'?

Comment: I've wondered the same thing, too, before...only I never thought of asking.

Comment: "Electrolytes" spring to mind, but are not exactly what you're looking for. "water ions" sounds good to me.

Comment: "Ionizable groups/compounds" could work

Comment: Wouldn't "ionizable groups/compounds" include salts in addition to acids and bases?